# Values are being assigned as null to the Database instead of 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Strange behavior on a code I'm trying to develop. 
I'm not understanding if it is something with the DB / code / permissions.. or other.

What is happening is that after filling up a form, some specific values which should be 0 are being passed to the database as null. If I see directly on the database, they are set as null. One of the fields is an "int" and the other is a "boolean".
For this code I'm using C# with ASP.net and the Entity Framework. The database is Microsoft SQL.

What could be useful to try to find the issue here?
What could I be missing?

I've tried so far the following:

- Changing settings on the database from accepting null values to not accept null values. With this when I try to save an object of this type, the object is not saved, as there are fields which are being passed as null. If I confirm with the debugger before the action to the Database, they are filled as 0 and not as null.
- Tried to change the way the users are authenticated. No changes.
- Rebuild the database with the previous settings. No changes.
- Rebuild the solution with all the database connection. No changes.
- Confirmed the methods / procedures to store and update the database, they seem to be correct.

Also, they work for the other fields in this object.

I've searched for some solutions here in stackoverflow and through the web, but until now, nothing has worked.

What else could I check to understand why the values reach the database as null?

The code:

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/prod/ficheiros/") + uplFicheiro.FileName;
uplFicheiro.SaveAs(path);
videos v = new videos();
v.id = 21;
v.video_name = VideoName.Text;
v.desc = DescVideo.Text;
v.aprov = true; <--- reaches DB as null
v.username = Page.User.Identity.Name;
v.url = "45";
v.num_visualizacoes = 0; <--- reaches DB as null

AcessoDados.DBVideos.insertVideo(v);
GridView1.DataBind();
CleanForm();
```

The insertVideo:

```
[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Insert, true)]
public static bool insertVideo(videos vid)
{
    bool res = false;
    try
    {

        contexto.Entry(vid).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
        res = (contexto.SaveChanges() != 0);

    }
    catch (Exception) { }

    return res;
}
```

I found the problem. The method which is writing on the database is not including the fields which I'm seeing as null. Hence the reason for them to reach the DB as null.
I need to correct this part which was generated by the Entity Model. Is there any way for the model to be corrected instead of I writing the methods manually?

Comment: Seeing the code would be useful (at least the relevant part where you think you are passing a 0 to the database). Without your code, all we can do is guess, and that isn't very useful at all.

Comment: Why do you need to set it 0 instead of NULL, can you give us an example? Usually NULL represents an unknown value, while 0 represents 0 itself. Just because the value is not provided in UI => suggests it should be saved as NULL.

Comment: What is happening is that even if I assign the v.aprov as true, it reaches the database as null. If it is false, it will also be as null on the database.

Comment: are you sure that the column names match and are mapped correctly between the model and the database? Maybe show us your model?

Comment: John, should I post here the whole model or some specific part?

Comment: Sidenote: the error handling in insertVideo is horrible. Just let the error bubble up. Do not use boolean return values for error propagation.

Comment: I found the problem. The method which is writing on the database is not including the fields which I'm seeing as null. Hence the reason for them to reach the DB as null.
I need to correct this part which was generated by the Entity Model. Is there any way for the model to be corrected instead of I writing the methods manually?

Answer (score 0):

-You need to go to properties for the colu
- check there General block -> Default Value and Binding
- make sure you set it to 0 (zero)
- If it is blank it will take by defaulf NULL